# When trying to make a bar plot in R, I get one box. How do I get the desired result?

Tags: r

I have a data frame read for a table that goes:

```
           V1           V2            V3            V4 V5
1     4.958077588 -3.265524806 12.2825957502  -9.205571807  1
2     1.203644083 -3.941877984 12.4758708139  -9.919943466  2
3     3.111368916 -4.922094042  7.8249212719  -8.662939867  1
```

and so on about 2000 times. I need to produce this:

[what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJEAP.png)

but when entering this code:

```
 barplot(nrow(mydata), names = mydata$V5,ylab="count",space=1)
```

all I get is a literal box. I need a frequency count for V5. How can I get it?

Comment: There is only a single unique value for column 'V5' and the frequency for that is 3.  So, you get only a single bar  With the whole dataset, may be `tbl <- table(mydata$V5);
  barplot(tbl, names = names(tbl),ylab="count",space=1)`

Comment: some of them have 2 as a V5 value, some have 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are looking for frequency count, then use `table` and then plot on that

```
tbl <- table(mydata$V5)
barplot(tbl, names = names(tbl),ylab="count",space=1)
```

[image]

---

Or using `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x= V5)) +
     geom_bar(aes(y = ..count..), fill = 'darkblue') +
     xlab('class') + 
     theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! is there a way to get that bottom line with the values in barplot rather than with ggplot?

Comment: @Dudeskiseph  You may need to specify `xaxt= 'n'` in `barplot` and then use `axis(1, ...`